# Convert string into bitwise comparison

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

Is it possible to easily convert the string

```
"4 | 2"
```

into a standard bitwise comparison so it returns 6.

So that I could accomplish something like this

```
$var1 = "4 | 2";
if(evalAsBitwise($var1) & 2) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does it need to support all bitwise operators (| & ^)? If you need to support all, you have to construct your own expression tree and handle the precedences etc.

Comment: As of right now it does not. Maybe in the future I might. Do you have an idea of a work around I could use for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split your string with space as the delimiter, you will get three parts: the first number, the operator, and the second number. In your function, you can use switch to determine what operator to use.

Something like

```
function evalAsBitwise($input) {      

   $parms = explode(" ", $input);       
   $next;
   $op;

   $total = array_shift($parms);

   while (!empty($parms)) {
     $next = array_shift($parms);
     if(is_numeric($next)) {
        switch($op) {
          case "|": $total = $total | intval($next); break;
          case "&": ...
        }
     }
     else {
       $op = $next;
     } 
   }// End while
   return $total;
}
```

You would also need to test for ~. But it gets more complicated if you need it do more complicated expressions like (a & b ^ (c ^ d)).

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need, but what if $var = "4 | 2 | 1". Is there another way I could write that so it works with X amount of pieces after the explode?

Comment: Does it need to handle parenthesis for order of operations?

Comment: I don't believe I will. Not yet at least. For now it is always going to be ($var1 & $var2). Where $var2 is a single int. And $var1 is going to be an OR comparison of 2-4 values.

Comment: I did end up using the explode and switch as well, but the loop idea @Htaras supplied was what really made it work so I awarded him the answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Ah, very nice. This is perfect. Switched this to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works only for bitwise OR.

```
function evalAsBitwise($var) {
    $values = explode($var);
    $result = 0;
    foreach ($$values as &$value) {
        $value = trim($value);
        $result = intVal($value) | intVal($result);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

My php skills are bit rusty, please check for syntax errors.